# Importing schema from json with optional value

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a table from a json datasource.

The problem is that there is a field in the json data that is not always present for every entry and looks like this.

```
[ { "k1" : "someValue",
    "optK" : { "nestedK" : true } },
  { "k1" : "someOtherValue" }
]
```

When I try to specify the optional field in the schema, all the entries without that field have all null value in the table:

```
columns:  k1        |  optK
row1:   "someValue"    [true]
row2:    null           null
```

is it possible to write a schema such that I would have null only in the column where the value is missing?

Like this:

```
columns:  k1            |  optK
row1:   "someValue"       "optV"
row2:   "someOtherValue"   null
```

My current code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.scalalang._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SparkSession}

val session = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("k1", StringType, false),
  StructField("optK", StructType(Seq(StructField("nestedK", BooleanType, false))), false)
))

val df = session.read.schema(schema).json("data.json")
df.registerTempTable("Mr_Table")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code/input data:

1. **Input data - JSON keys aren't in quote.**

You can use avoid this problem, by one of the following options:

- Updating the input data by adding quotes to the json keys
- Using `.option("allowUnquotedFieldNames",true)` in the following way:

  ```
  val df = session.read.option("allowUnquotedFieldNames",true).schema(schema).json("data.json")
  ```

2. **A `string` field in the input data was defined as `boolean` in the schema** schema should be updated to be:

   val schema = StructType(Seq(
     StructField("k1", StringType, false),
     StructField("optK", StructType(Seq(StructField("nestedK", StringType, false))), false)
   ))

3. JSON data format, **I've update the sample json input to be in `json lines` format**:

```scala
{ k1 : "someValue", optK : { nestedK : "optV" } }
{ k1 : "someOtherValue" }
```

---

Running the modify code shows the following:

```
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application_xxx).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_141)   
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)   
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.scalalang._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SparkSession}    
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("k1", StringType, false),
  StructField("optK", StructType(Seq(StructField("nestedK", StringType, false))), false)
))    
val df = spark.read.option("allowUnquotedFieldNames",true).schema(schema).json("s3 location of data.json")       
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.scalalang._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SparkSession}
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(k1,StringType,false), StructField(optK,StructType(StructField(nestedK,StringType,false)),false))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [k1: string, optK: struct<nestedK: string>]

scala> df.show
+--------------+------+
|            k1|  optK|
+--------------+------+
|     someValue|[optV]|
|someOtherValue|  null|
+--------------+------+
```

Comment: ok, sorry. Clearly I didn't copy/paste the json from the real file and I added some mistakes. Assuming booleans are booleans and the json is properly formatted. What do you think may be the reason why I see all null values in the table when I run SELECT * FROM Table?

Comment: @LucaS. - First, I'd suggest testing if the solution I provided is working for you. I've provided both updated input file, and spark code. which was tested to be working on my machine.

Comment: @LucaS. - Note that: it wasn't easy to solve the question you posted, with the data/source code you provided. It even harder to find the problem in unknown input and unknown source code

Comment: @LucaS. - did you test the solution I've provided? did it work for you?